# why my listeners does not work on extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

here is the code and also i want onPaste event instead of click but nothing working

```
var mpan0 = new Ext.form.TextField({
    name:'mpan[]' ,
    value:0 , 
    allowblank:false , 
    enableKeyEvents:true ,
    fieldLabel:'Mpan',
    maxLength:2,
    width:35
    });

mpan0.addListener('click', function(){ 
    alert( "amiy");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ext.form.TextField does not have a 'click' event. You can see the events it does support at:

http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.TextField

The closest I can think of to what you are seeking is the 'focus' event.

If you really must have a click event you can try attaching a listener to the field object's fundamental DOM element:

```
Ext.form.TextField({
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function( field ) {
            field.getEl().on('click', function( event, el ) {
                 // do something on click
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I can't claim to know how successful that will be, however.

Documentation on Ext.Element's click event can be found at:

http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element

Comment: This listener will be triggered even when clicking on the field label. You should bind the event to the input element inside like so: `var inputElement = field.getEl().down('input');` and even then, clicking on field label can fire the click event on the input field itself, that's why you should use `mousedown` event like so: `inputElement.on( { mousedown: function() { // ..`

Answer (score 2):

```
yourtextfield = new Ext.form.TextField({
    id:'yourtextfield ',
    readOnly : true,
    listeners: {'render': function(cmp) { 
      cmp.getEl().on('click', function( event, el ) {
      alert("You click text field");
      });            
    }}        
});
```

This works.

Answer (score -2):

ExtJs uses `on`, so it should be

```
mpan0.on("click", function(){
    alert("amiy");
});
```

But you can also add it declaratively

```
var mpan0 = new Ext.form.TextField({
    name:'mpan[]' ,
    value:0 , 
    allowblank:false , 
    enableKeyEvents:true ,
    fieldLabel:'Mpan',
    maxLength:2,
    width:35,
    listeners: {
        "click": function() {
            alert("amiy");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Then there is something else wrong - the above code is correct. Have you tried a debugger? Btw, `on` and `addListener` is the same..

Comment: hi i do not know how to use debugger , also i tried ur code i donot know its nor working in any condition , i think we have to find the variable that needs to be set for activating on click ,
or there is an answer which works which is given by "owlness" ,May be u can suggest better code , or u get something out of it